# Cannot find option to create iOS App Development certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

[image]

See this image the iOS App Development option is disable, How I can enable it.

Comment: You don't have the right permissions. Get your Team Agent to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a Team Agent or Admin to create development certificates.

[image]

<sup><sup><sup><sup>[[Source]](https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/)</sup></sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Some time delete old certificate and than try to create new one.